# How can I stop a function executed with Redux architecture in SwiftUI?

Tags: redux, swiftui

I am using TabView as page. I have 2 screens. When I switch from the first screen to the second screen, I want the operations of the first screen to stop. When I switch from the second screen to the first screen, the animation and the sequence of operations are disrupted and the order of the texts appearing on the screen is distorted. The problem is in the TypingTextAnimation screen..
However, when I did not use the Redux architecture, it was not a problem. The problem started when I switched to Redux architecture.

[image]

**Reducer:**

```
func countReducer(state: inout AppState, action: AppAction) {
    switch action {
    case let countAction as StudyAction:
        switch countAction {
        case .increment:
            state.cards.append(NumberStep(index: (state.cards.last?.index ?? 0) + 1, number: Int.random(in: 20...30)))
            state.currentStep += 1
            state.cards.removeFirst()
            state.currentNumber = state.cards.first?.number ?? 0
            state.currentNumberWithString = NumberConfig.shared.convertNumberToString(number: state.cards.first?.number ?? 0)
        case .resetStep:
            state.cards = []
            state.currentStep = 1
        case .addTreeTimesRandomNumberStep:
            state.cards = [
                NumberStep(index: 1, number: Int.random(in: 20...30)),
                NumberStep(index: 2, number: Int.random(in: 20...30)),
                NumberStep(index: 3, number: Int.random(in: 20...30))
            ]
            state.currentNumber = state.cards.first?.number ?? 0
            state.currentNumberWithString = NumberConfig.shared.convertNumberToString(number: state.cards.first?.number ?? 0)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**MainView:**

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NumberToTextTutorialView()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemFill))
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(8)
            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemFill))
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(8)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

**NumberToTextTutorialView:**

```
struct NumberToTextTutorialView: View {
    @State var didTypingFinish: Bool = false
    @State var stringNumber: String = ""
    @State private var fullScreen: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sayıdan Yazıya")
                .bold()
                .padding(.bottom, 16)
            Text("Description Text...")
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            Spacer()
            CardView(didTypingFinish: $didTypingFinish, stringNumber: $stringNumber, isCorrect: .constant(false), isAuto: true)
            TypingTextAnimation(didTypingFinish: $didTypingFinish, finalText: $stringNumber)
            Spacer()
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { number in
                        Button {
                            fullScreen = true
                        } label: {
                            Text("\(number * 100) - \((number * 100) + 100)")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .label))
                                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
                                .background(.orange)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $fullScreen) {
                NumberToTextStudyView()
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 24)
    }
}
```

**TypingTextAnimation:**

```
struct TypingTextAnimation: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var opacity: Bool = false
    @State private var offset: Int = 0
    @State private var statusColor: Color = Color(uiColor: .label)
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    @Binding var didTypingFinish: Bool
    @Binding var finalText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
            HStack(spacing: 1) {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 2, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .opacity(isAnimating ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.easeInOut.repeatForever(), value: isAnimating)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation {
                            isAnimating.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(lineWidth: 2).foregroundColor(statusColor).background(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemBackground)).cornerRadius(8))
            .onChange(of: finalText, perform: { _ in
                typeWriter()
            })
    }
    
    func typeWriter(at position: Int = 0) {
        if position == 0 {
            text = " "
            didTypingFinish = false
        }
        if position < finalText.count {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                text.append(finalText[position])
                typeWriter(at: position + 1)
                statusColor = .orange
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                statusColor = .green
                delete()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func delete() {
        
        if text.count != 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                text.removeAll()
                didTypingFinish = true
            }
        } else {
            if offset < finalText.count - 1 {
                offset += 1
                typeWriter()
            } else {
                offset = 0
                typeWriter()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TypingTextAnimation_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TypingTextAnimation(didTypingFinish: .constant(false), finalText: .constant("deneme"))
    }
}

extension String {
    subscript(offset: Int) -> Character {
        self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
    }
}
```